# Google Drive Api thumbnailLink returns 500 error status code

Tags: react-native, google-drive-api

**Premise:** I have successfully uploaded the Image file to drive with a customized Thumbnail using drive API.
Then, I used list API and queried all fields where Maily for the context I got

*{"hasThumbnail":true,

"thumbnailLink":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/cv0mHJqt00lm0KU1dv9viebh7757-LK2J02uGsGImR0Eei50KF7Dt091L6om8Zccdt1Nxzld0i4FsuA=s220",

"thumbnailVersion":"1",}*

then I used thumbnailLink to fetch the thumbnail which I have uploaded, I tried to fetch them with credetial and I have the permission to access the content also..

**Problem :** After the fetch request I got  error code 500,

> {"config": {"adapter": [Function xhrAdapter], "data": undefined, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Authorization": "Bearer undefined"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "get", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Uc5tD9HrJBfuEVW8dFA2ztgqvgfrMhpWUd_syGNco4PtTGSCSuDLOjLgObr7-ZdjKjT1xvlHhG7eWnk=s220", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}, "data": ".........(Some HTML)..............., ", "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_subscriptions": [], "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Uc5tD9HrJBfuEVW8dFA2ztgqvgfrMhpWUd_syGNco4PtTGSCSuDLOjLgObr7-ZdjKjT1xvlHhG7eWnk=s220", "readyState": 4, "responseHeaders": {"Alt-Svc": "h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"", "Content-Length": "1730", "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "Date": "Wed, 17 Aug 2022 10:34:10 GMT", "Server": "fife", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-xss-protection": "0"}, "responseURL": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Uc5tD9HrJBfuEVW8dFA2ztgqvgfrMhpWUd_syGNco4PtTGSCSuDLOjLgObr7-ZdjKjT1xvlHhG7eWnk=s220", "status": 500, "timeout": 0, "upload": {}, "withCredentials": true}, "status": 500, "statusText": undefined}

```js
const func = async () => {
  try {
    let result = await axios.get(
      `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Uc5tD9HrJBfuEVW8dFA2ztgqvgfrMhpWUd_syGNco4PtTGSCSuDLOjLgObr7-ZdjKjT1xvlHhG7eWnk=s220`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + drive.accessToken,
          // "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    console.log("result", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response);
  }
};
```

**The above snippet is how I fetched it.....**

**Conclusion: I want Thumbnail which I uploaded with my file and I am not able to fetch it. Please Help!! Thanks...**

Comment: Can you see the custom thumbnail in the web interface?

Comment: @Mila No not working! I pasted the link in the crome but same response came up... there was a server-side HTML saying-----> "The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. If the problem persists, please "google.com/support .. your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it. That’s all we know."

Comment: scopes: [
        GoogleSignIn.SCOPES.DRIVE_APPFOLDER,
        GoogleSignIn.SCOPES.DRIVE_FULL,
        GoogleSignIn.SCOPES.DRIVE_APPS,
        GoogleSignIn.SCOPES.DRIVE_FILE,
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly",
      ],
I have used all the scopes which are there.....